# using match parent in grid layout

Tags: android, grid-layout

Hi i have an issue with an activity in my app where it doesn't fill all the available space here is a screenshot [image: screenshot on phone]

Now here it looks fine its a relative layout on the right with buttons inside and a gridlayout holding all the animals When a button in the relative layout is clicked it changes the images in the gridlayout but when its shown on a tablet the animals take up the top left corner instead of stretching to meet the other layout my question is is there something I can do to make the gridlayout fill this space or is it more practical to set up a grid view?
here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MusicActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:background="@drawable/choose_animals2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:background="@drawable/choose_letters"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:background="@drawable/piano_icon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/Button4"
            android:background="@drawable/drum_icon0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/Button5"
            android:background="@drawable/choose_numbers"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nxtbtn"
            android:id="@+id/Button6"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/secondLayout">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="13">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/lion_icon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/lionhead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="@drawable/dog_icon"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/doghead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:background="@drawable/cat_icon"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cathead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/duck_icon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/duckhead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/monkey_icon"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/monkeyhead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:background="@drawable/sheep_icon"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/sheephead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pig_icon"

            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pighead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ele_icon"

            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/elephanthead"/>


        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions

Comment: post your layout xml.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with android:stretchMode="XXX"? /   android:numColumns="auto_fit" /  android:columnWidth="" on Tablet Screen size

Comment: no im very new to android my stretchmode at the moment for the gridlayout is collumnwidth @Hamid Shatu updated to include code

Comment: How did that even compile, `android:orientation` is only for `LinearLayout` isn't it?

Comment: Yeah it was a linear layout once upon a time the height and width are now providing the orientation so thank you I'll take that out but I know there's a few things wrong but could we please focus on the question

Comment: Use android:layout_weight and weightsum to desing the layout.

Comment: GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of weight, as defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space between multiple components.
Some common use-cases may nevertheless be accommodated as follows. To place equal amounts of space around a component in a cell group; use CENTER alignment (or gravity). For complete control over excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout subview to hold the components in the associated cell group.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this (see my last comment below) and it does work for the most part just sticking in a linear layout for each row of my grid essentially
Leaving me to wonder why the gridlayout is needed sorry for the broad answer but I've just added a linear subview to display the images nicely as described herehttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html